# Filtering depth data of the form sensor_msgs/Image from Kinect 2

Tags: ros, navigation, transforms, iai-kinect2, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

**--See Update 1--**

I am using [iai_kinect2](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2) to get a depth cloud in the form `sensor_msgs/Image`. Now, I want to filter this depth cloud (like remove points on the ground, outliers, etc.). I can use a [Pass-through filter](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.php) but it works only on `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` whereas I have `sensor_msgs/Image`. Now, my question is :

1. I can convert `sensor_msgs/Image` to `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` using [depth_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc) and do filtering but then, how can I convert the filtered Pointcloud (in form `sensor_msgs/Pointcloud2`) back to depth cloud (in form `sensor_msgs/Image`) to use it with `depthimage_to_laserscan` ?
2. Or, How can I directly filter `depth_cloud` in the form `sensor_msgs/Image` using pass-through filters, etc.. ?
3. I know I can use `pointcloud_to_laserscan` to convert `filtered_pointcloud` to laser scan but it will be less efficient and therefore, I want to know how can I do the above conversion or directly filter the `depth_cloud`?

**Update 1 :**
As suggested by @Akif, I used `pcl:toROSMsg` to convert `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` to `sensor_msgs/Image`. It compiled properly but during run time, when I try to visualize it in RVIZ, I get the following :

```
MessageFilter [target=kinect2_link ]: Discarding message from [unknown_publisher] due to empty frame_id.  This message will only print once.
```

When I do `rostopic echo /kinect2/depthcloud_filtered`, I get

```
header: 
  seq: 2139
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
height: 1
width: 68227
encoding: bgr8
is_bigendian: 0
step: 204681
data: [0, 0, 181, 209, 216, 179, 207, 214, 179, 207, 214, 0, 0, 0, 175, 204, 211, 176, 205, 212, 176, 205, 210, 177, 206, 211, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 179, 207, 214, 179, 208, 215, 181, 210, 217, 0, 0, 0, 178, 207, 214, 179, 208, 215, 180, 209, 216, 175, 204, 209, 175, 205, 210, 174, 203, 210, 0, 0, 0, 174, 203, 210, 175, 204, 211, 174, 203, 210, 176, 204, 211, 177, 205, 212, 0, 0, 0, 178, 207, 212, 180, 209, 214, 178, 206, 213, 179, 208, 215, 177, 209, 215, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 180, 209, 216, 174, 203, 208, 174, 203, 208, 176, 205, 210, 174, 203, 208, 175, 204, 209, 175, 205, 210, 175, 205, 210, 175, 204, 211, 175, 204, 211, 173, 205, 211, 172, 204, 210, 173, 205, 211, 173, 205, 211, 176, 205, 212, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 179, 208, 215, 171, 203, 209, ....... ]
```

It looks like there is some problem here. It does not have any time stamp or `frame_id`. Does anyone has any idea why is this happening? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223299/filtering-depth-data-of-the-form-sensor_msgs/image-from-kinect-2/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will answer through your **1)** option.

In PCL we have [pcl_conversions header](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/pcl_conversions/html/namespacepcl.html). With help of it, you can use [::toROSMsg](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/pcl_conversions/html/pcl__conversions_8h_source.html#l00487) to convert `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` to `sensor_msgs/Image`.

Also there is a [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/CloudToImage) on this. Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2016-01-01**:
@Akif! `::toROSMsg` extracts the RGB image from the depth cloud. I just want to convert the format of depth cloud to `sensor_msgs/Image` from `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`.. like `iai_kinect2` ros package publishes depth cloud as `sensor_msg/Image`.. Please correct me if I am wrong! TIA

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2016-01-04**:
Hi.. I have updated my original question. Thanks!

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2017-05-19**:
Hi Naman, could plz get me starting to use kinect v2 for detecting the object and depth data, I have installed everything, but I don't know how to run, cuz all codes for kinect v1